# Unable to find template in SQL

Tags: sql

I can't find the model, why?

Thank you.

```
SELECT Last_Name, Birth_Date, main_phone_num
FROM customers
WHERE Birth_Date LIKE '____-06%'
```

Comment: What does your date field look like?

Comment: Thank you . Now I have found

Comment: The above *implies* your column `Birth_Date` is a string based data type, not a `date`. I hope not.

Answer (score 2):

You are using string functions on a date -- **bad**.  Both MySQL and SQL Server offer a function `day()` that returns the day of the month.  You can use tahat:

```
where day(birth_date) = 6
```

Comment: Thank you . Now I have found